# Cannot persist many-to-many relationship correctly

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

`Article` and `Image` have many-to-many relationship and their intermediate table is `ArticleImage`. I expect I'll see 1 rows in `Article` table, 3 rows in `Image` table, and 3 rows in `ArticleImage` table. `Article` and `ArticleImage` part are working as expected, however, there is 0 row in `Image` table and the foreigh-key column 'image_id' in `ArticleImage` table of that 3 newly-added rows are 'NULL'. What am I missing to persist rows in `Image` table correctly?
(there is no error printed)

My code:

```
db_session = some_function()  # get connection to database here
try:
    article = Article()
    db_session.add(article)
    article.name = 'new post #1'
    article.author = 'pojan'
    article.images.append(Image('img1.jpg'))
    article.images.append(Image('img2.jpg'))
    article.images.append(Image('img3.jpg'))
    db_session.merge(article)
    db_session.commit()

    print db_session.query(Article).count()       # 1
    print db_session.query(ArticleImage).count()  # 3
    print db_session.query(Image).count()         # 0 <- error here, images are not added 

except Exception as e:
    print e
```

I have also tried the following code, now the `Image` would be added to database, but the image_id column in `ArticleImage` still remain as NULL:

```
    article = Article()
    db_session.add(article)
    article.name = 'new post #1'
    article.author = 'pojan'

    image1 = Image('img1.jpg')
    image2 = Image('img2.jpg')
    image3 = Image('img3.jpg')
    db_session.add(image1)
    db_session.add(image2)
    db_session.add(image3)

    article.images.append(image1)
    article.images.append(image2)
    article.images.append(image3)
    db_session.merge(article)
    db_session.commit()
```

My model:

```
class Image(EntityClass):
    attributes = ['id', 'name', 'path']

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    path = Column(String(255), nullable=False, unique=True)

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.path = '/root/' + name

class ArticleImage(EntityClass):

    article_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('article.id'))
    image_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('image.id'))
    image = relationship(Image)
    position = Column(Integer)

class Article(EntityClass):

    attributes = ['id','name','author']

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    _images = relationship(ArticleImage,
             order_by=[ArticleImage.position],
             collection_class=ordering_list('position'))
    images = association_proxy('_images', 'image')

    name = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
    author = Column(String(255), nullable=False)
```

(the design is base on an [article](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/S4_8PeRBNJw) I found on internet, and I made some minor changes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [article](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/S4_8PeRBNJw) you refer to, you should also add a constructor in `ArticleImage` to associate `ArticleImage` with `Image` when an `ArticleImage` oject is created, otherwise `ArticleImage` would never know which image row it should refer to.

```
class ArticleImage(EntityClass):

    article_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('article.id'))
    image_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('image.id'))
    image = relationship(Image)
    position = Column(Integer)

    def __init__(self, image=None):
        self.image = image
```

Answer (score 0):

You missed primary key in `ArticleImage` compared to the example you give.

I would get

> sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Mapper Mapper|ArticleImage|article_image could not assemble any primary key columns for mapped table 'article_image'

with your `ArticleImage` code.